# how to input value in time(7) type using asp.net mvc 5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I working with Asp.Net MVC using database first workflow. In one of my tables I have a field to store only time value using `time(7)` type. When I enter data using sql server like `08:00:00`, it is inserted without any errors but when I post data using form this error occurs `Validation failed for one or more entities` on `db.SaveChanges();`
ModelState is valid and I'm sure there's something wrong with the time input format. Further how can we give time input something like `08:00:00 AM`?

Model

```
public partial class Doctor
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Doctor()
        {
            this.Appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public bool Gender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date_Joined { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Left { get; set; }
        public string Specialization { get; set; }
        public string Academic_Record { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Is_Left { get; set; }
        public System.TimeSpan Work_Start_Time { get; set; }
        public System.TimeSpan Work_End_Time { get; set; }
        public int Fees { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Doctor</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "true", new { id = "male" })
            @Html.Label("male", "Male")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "false", new { id = "female" })
            @Html.Label("female", "Female")
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date_Joined, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_Joined, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_Joined, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date_Left, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date_Left, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date_Left, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Specialization, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Specialization, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Specialization, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Academic_Record, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Academic_Record, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Academic_Record, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Is_Left, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Is_Left)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Is_Left, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Work_Start_Time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Work_Start_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Work_Start_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Work_End_Time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Work_End_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Work_End_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fees, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fees, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fees, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Age,Gender,Email,Phone,Address,Date_Joined,Date_Left,Speci= alization,Academic_Record,Is_Left,Work_Start_Time,Work_End_Time,Fees")] Doctor doctor)
        {
            object errors;
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(e => e.Errors);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Doctors.Add(doctor);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(doctor);
        }
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: @Mr.AF included the code in the question ...

Comment: i can't see where you open your db and trying to add time ! where is that?

Comment: just post where the error threw .

Comment: on `db.SaveChanges();` statement in controller's create method

Comment: What do you mean by opening the db and adding time? I'm using create view to enter data into table

Comment: Which field uses time(7) constraint? `Validation failed for one or more entities` is a broad message when EF validation fails, check inner exception message or error reason to find out problem source.

Comment: Work_Start_Time & Work_End_Time cause issue I guess because without these fields there is no issue

Comment: I solved my issue ...